# Google Colab: not using all training samples

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm loading the MNIST data into Google Colab, which I can see is about 60,000 samples

[image]

But for some reason it will only train on 1875 samples:

[image]

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1875 is not the number of samples, it is number of steps.

Keras uses batches to train and default batch size is 32.

60000 / 32 = 1875

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It was driving me made because it displays differently on my laptop